# jquery countdown timer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery countdown timer here http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/ and I have found that if I browse to another tab in firefox, the seconds disappear. Sometimes they come back but usually they are gone. The countdown is still working as the minutes tick over.

Could this be because I am using a float left on the digits? Anyone else have this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I went to the site and viewed the demo, went to a different tab, came back and everything was fine?  Post your code.?

Comment: I'm going to -1 this as you say your using some float left stuff, then don't show any code... I get the same issue though... the seconds seem to flicker when the page is reshown. I'm on the current Chrome Dev (v13 or so)

Comment: I am using the latest Firefox so it could be a browser issue, not code issue. Time to search for another countdown timer.

Comment: It's the browser that's the issue I believe.  I have the same issue with jQuery's .delay() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out the example you linked to.  What version of Firefox are you using?

On the example it says:

> "This page has been tested with IE 6,
>   IE 7, IE 8, FF 3, Safari 4, Opera 9,
>   Chrome 4 "

I think the issue might have to do with what browser version or plugins you are using.  I just tested it in IE8 and everything worked fine for me.

Short of that and without taking a look at your code or changing the plugin source, I am not sure we can help you resolve the issue.